# 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript, navbar

I've written this to display block or display none for a navbar. Though I have a form that submits and display none on the element that is display block by default, which causes there to be no tab that displays active class.

My goal is to be able to hide my div after submit and avoid the classist of null error. Any and all ideas are appreciated. Thanks

```
    // object
 const onePage = {
          pages: [], // property to save pages in
          show: new Event('show'),
          init: function(){
            onePage.pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
            //listener for show event, calling function
            onePage.pages.forEach((pg)=>{
              pg.addEventListener('show', onePage.pageShown);
            })      
            //listener for click event, calling function
            document.querySelectorAll('.nav-t').forEach((link)=>{
                  link.addEventListener('click',onePage.nav);
            })
            // showing on which page we are viewing 
            history.replaceState({}, 'Reporting', '#Reporting');
            window.addEventListener('hashchange', onePage);
          },
          nav: function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();  
            let currentPage = ev.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-target');
            document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
            document.getElementById(currentPage).classList.add('active'); // where the error occurs
            history.pushState({}, currentPage, `#${currentPage}`);
            document.getElementById(currentPage).dispatchEvent(onePage.show);
          },
 }
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onePage.init);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the result to a variable and check if it's null first.

```
nav: function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let currentPage = ev.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-target');
  let curPage = document.getElementById(currentPage);
  if (curPage) {
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
    curPage.classList.add('active'); // where the error occurs
    history.pushState({}, currentPage, `#${currentPage}`);
    curPage.dispatchEvent(onePage.show);
  }
},
```

Comment: I added this suggestion to the nav function and it doesn't work. I get the ability to click back to the first tab but the 3rd div shows up instead. Though it still returns null after clicking 3 times on the tab.

Comment: Maybe you need to put the history code inside the `if` as well, since it uses `currentPage` as well.

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable, I can't tell what you've done there. I revised the answer.

Comment: I don't know your application, I don't know how the navbar works. You asked how to fix the error about `getElementById()` returning `null`, I showed how to do that. You're on your own for the rest.

Comment: no problem. Thanks for the help! It does not return null anymore you're right! Though I'll have to find another solution for how it displays block and none.